# jpa left join eclipse-link

Tags: jpa, join, eclipselink

i'm using eclipse-link 2 &  have 3 entities:
Parent, Child & ChildInfo.
Parent has onetomany to Child.
Child has 1to1 to ChildInfo.

1. i want to get a Parent with all children object in one call
   "select P from Parent left join fetch P.children where P.id=:id"
   this will only give result when P has at least 1 child (i thought it's a left outer join)
2. i want to have also all the children & belongings childinfos with 1 call
   as jpa doesnt support navigation p.children.childinfo, is there any way to achieve that ? using hints(QueryHints.FETCH, "P.children.info") is not a good option as if i have over 1000 children there'll over 1 thousands of sql-queries fired to get the children info. i also dont want to give Child.childinfo eager-fetch option but rather only at query-level.

thanx alot

Answer (score 0):

The first query (once fixed) should definitely return the parent and its children, even if it doesn't have any:

```
select p from Parent p left join fetch p.children where p.id = :id
```

To fetch the childInfos, you need to assign an alias to the child:

```
select p from Parent p 
left join fetch p.children child
left join fetch child.childInfo
where p.id = :id
```

I have no concrete experience with EclipseLink, but such a query definitely works in Hibernate, and is, AFAIK, valid JPQL. So it should work in EclipseLink.